# convert dictionary to abstract matrix in julia

Tags: arrays, dictionary, type-conversion, julia

I'm trying to do dimension reduction, and I got a:

```
d = Dict{Tuple{String, String}, Vector{Float64}}
```

Trying to apply `umap` on it.

While `umap` can only accepts *abstractmatrix*, so I do `collect(d)`, but the dict is converted into vector, not array.

How do I convert it correctly to successfully apply `umap`?

Comment: Just a side note, there are several terminology errors in your post. Vectors are aliases (just another name) for 1-dimensionars arrays and matrix for 2-dimenational ones. You can't convert anything to an "abstract" type as in Julia you can't instantiate objects out of them, only create child types. If a function is defined to accept an abstract type it does any of its child types

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

`hcat(values(d)...)`

using `values` you get a vector of vectors, the dictionary values. And `hcat` will concatenate them horizontally, however this function takes each vector as a different argument and therefore you need to splat this array into its elements, that is what the three dots `...` do.

Check the documentation for [splatting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#...-splits-one-argument-into-many-different-arguments-in-function-calls)

As noted in the comments, a more efficient alternative is

`reduce(hcat, values(d))`

which achieves the same avoiding splatting.

Comment: Splatting can be problematic from a performance perspective. It is normally better to use `reduce`, as in `reduce(hcat, values(d))`.

Comment: totally right, what should I do then, edit my answer or will you post one?

Comment: Just add a comment to your post.

Comment: Thanks for your help! While I found that the dictionary given has different lengths of vectors, and I need to make vectors have same length to use `reduce(hcat, values(d))`, is there any efficient way to make them have same length? Like cut long vectors to the shortest length.

Comment: I think it might be good to ask a new question for this? Out of curiosity what kind of dimensionality reduction are you trying that works on vectors of different size?